# call from form alter - undefined function error

Tags: 7, theming

I try to use code for redirecting after submitting a form, but I am getting the below error:

> undefined function my_search_form_submit_funtion in form.inc.

Why do I get this error? Thank you. 
The module name is `utility`.

```
function utility_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_search_form_submit_funtion';
  }
}
function my_search_form_submit_function(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $search_str = $form_state['values']['search_block_form'];
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_goto('search', array('query' => array('search_api_multi_fulltext' => $search_str)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo error in your code.

Change

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_search_form_submit_funtion';
```

To

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_search_form_submit_function';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake in your function name, in the line
 $form['#submit'][] = 'my_search_form_submit_funtion';
you can replace '**funtion**' with '**function**' to make your code run perfect.